# Facebook Graph API, FQL returns empty comment even though comments are present

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In my one of the project, there is a functionality where user can share some articles. For sharing article, I have used following code.

```
  <a title="Share this answer on facebook" 
    onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u= 
    {URL_TO_SHARE}',
    'facebook-share-dialog','width=500,height=300'); 
    return false;">
    SHARE ON FB
   </a>
```

The above code absolutely works fine and shares my article to my wall. Now I want to get all comments posted on above shared link(article).

So for that, I have used following code (I am using facebook-php-sdk):

```
$facebook->api('/comments?id=' . $url); 
//$url is the url of the shared link which is correct
```

But above api calls returns empty array, even though there are comments present on this article.

I have also tried following `FQL` query,  but that also returns empty array.

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time FROM comment 
WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url = '{MY_URL}')
```

To cross check, I went to [Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and checked over there. But even there also it returns empty array, as if there are no comments.

**UPDATE:**

For testing purpose, I have used [Facebook Comment Box Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to my page, and posted some comment from that plugin.

Now when I fire query to Graph API, it gives me all comments posted from comment plugin.
But not what I have posted from Facebook Wall.

Please suggest how can I resolve the above issue.

-- Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you able to get the data with the object_id obtained? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=OBJECT_ID

Comment: No, I am not. It shows me "An error has occurred" message. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20id%2C%20text%2C%20time%2C%20fromid%20FROM%20comment%20WHERE%20object_id%3D'413579398751708'

Comment: Which url are you looking for?

Comment: It is http://www.philozophy.agstechnologies.com/answer/2/95

Comment: When I execute FQL to get comment_count from link stat, it correctly shows count, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20comment_count%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.philozophy.agstechnologies.com%2Fanswer%2F2%2F95'

Comment: You can run the inner query `SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url = '{MY_URL}'` to get the object_id. But the thing is I cant see any fb_comments used there.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use the following query in fql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure this website is using Facebook comments plugin? you can retrieve only those comments with the comments_fbid, and I guess only if you have the required permission (same app access)

UPDATE:

> Now when I fire query to Graph API, it gives me all comments posted from comment plugin. But not what I have posted from Facebook Wall.

As I said, to retrieve comments on your Facebook Wall when you don't have the postID, you have to query Facebook to retrieve your feed, and then search inside the received posts data to find the one containing your link.
Then you'll have all the comments.

Try in the graph explorer, with the request `?fields=feed`. You will have an object with a feed key, and feed.data will contain an array with all your posts. For each post, look at the link property and find your link. The comments property will contain all the comments made on this facebook post.

Comment: No, I am not using facebook comments plugin. But I guess I can retrieve comment without using plugin as well.

Comment: I guess not! the comments_fbid is specifically made to retrieve the id of the comments plugin element. So without the comments plugin, this id is just the id of the webpage, and then you cannot access to any of its comments. 
The only comments you could obtain could be the comments on facebook on a shared link of this webpage, but even for that, you would need some permissions

Comment: Yes, I am only interested in obtaining comments on facebook on shared link. Can you tell me what kind of permission is needed.

Comment: well I guess you need the read_stream permission from the user who shared the link on facebook...

Comment: are you the one who shared the link on facebook?

Comment: Yes, I have shared the link on facebook.

Comment: Ok I see. When you shared that link on Facebook (with fb API) Facebook answers with the post id. You have to check for comments with this Id and not with the URL of the link. You can retrieve the comments of the shared link post you've made. Do you have the post id?

Comment: No, I don't have post Id, I am sharing the link using, https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{MY_URL}}, and it does not return POST ID.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the post id, after sharing link?

Comment: Not simple... You have to query for all your posts and then search your link inside the answer.

Comment: Got it, so you can't get comment on shared post directly using graph api. You can only get those comments posted by comment box plugin widget.

Comment: not directly, or you have to query for all the posts on your feed and their comments.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are associated to Facebook Graph Objects.  In your above example you are actually referring to multiple open graph objects, which is part of the problem.

Object #1 is your Website Article.  If you type in your Article URL into the Facebook Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) you will get information about it as Facebook has cached it into the graph store.  At the bottom of this page you will see a field called Graph API.  The ID in the url provided is your Graph Object ID for that page.  You can even click that link to see the data for that object.

Objects #2-#n are your Shares.  When your visitors "Share" the article to their timeline, they are creating a "Post" to their timeline.  Each of those "Posts" has a different and unique Open Graph Object ID.  The commenting plugin then attaches a unique comment board to that unique post.

Thus for one article from your website, in terms of commenting, you will have one conversation from your Website Page using the open graph object id for the article url, then a unique conversations for each post that is shared on a users stream.

It sounds like you want all of these merged together so there is only 1 commenting object.

In order to do that when you make your call to Facebook to post a comment, you have to ensure you are providing the ID of the Article Object.

Instead of this...
$facebook->api('/comments?id=' . $url);

Try a POST call to:
"https://graph.facebook.com/[OPEN-GRAPH-ID-OF-ARTICLE]/comments?message='my message'"

This process is outlined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-comments/#creating

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Ben